# Particle physics plots: on the x-axis, Mass or (Mass)$^2$?

Tags: particle-physics, particle-detectors

This might be very silly, but I have seen particle physics graphs plotted against $mc^2$ and others plotted against $(mc^2)^2$, which is actually the invariant $p_{\mu}p^{\mu}$.

Is there a physical difference between the two choices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This choice just depends on the experiment conducted.  Some plots expect the trendline to give an implied value $mc^2$, while others track $(mc^2)^2$.

My personal favorites on these plots are Curie plots which purportedly show that the square of the mass of the neutrino is negative. Good luck determining what that means.  :)